# Firebase cloud functions working in emulator, but failed to deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working for a mini project,  I need to call an external api but I could not deploy the function, I am having a the following error,

> Error: There was an error deploying functions

I could not find anything in firebase-debug.log. when I called the same function as http triggered function and test it from the emulator, it worked, However, I could not deploy.

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule("every 1 minute").onRun(async (context) => {
  const response = await getResponse();
  functions.logger.log(response);
  return null;
});

function getResponse() {
  const url = "https://pikas.techinsight.com.my/kgateway/testing.php";
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      return resolve(response.data.split("\n"));
    }).catch((error) => {
      functions.logger.log(error);
      return reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Here's the debug.log

```
[debug] [2021-11-15T18:41:34.063Z] Error: Failed to update function scheduledFunction in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:38:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:250:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:134:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:75:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Please help me to see what i am doing wrong

Comment: Did you succeed? Sometimes the error goes away on their own.

Comment: @pagep No I didn't, I have moved evry functions to app engine for the mean time. It only happens with this functions, there are other functions in the file, they get deployed without any problem.

Comment: I would try to delete the function from the firebase interface. Check that scheduler was also deleted and than try to re-deploy it. I've run into weird problems with deploy of functions several times over the past year and in case I couldn't find a problem on my side it started working again the next day ...

Comment: Had this same issue. Nothing is helping. Tried deleting gcf artifacts, re-installing firebase tools. Removed all the functions. Something got stuck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed all your dependencies inside `/functions` folder. I had installed some dependencies in the root of the project by a mistake. The emulator is still able to resolve those dependencies but deployment fails.